# "Update security settings" in portal_workflow triggers catalog metadata update unnecessarily?

Tags: plone, zope

Plone 3.3.5: We have a middle sized Plone site and we'd like to update its workflows. Since it's a long-running process we noticed something strange going on. Our Archetypes accessors, not security related, where called when hitting "Update security settings" in portal_workflow.

Looks like the culprit is update_metadata=1 default setting in ZCatalog:

```
-> self.plone_log("treatmentToImagingHours: %s"%str(treatmentToImagingHours))
(Pdb) bt
  /Users/moo/sits/parts/zope2/lib/python/ZServer/PubCore/ZServerPublisher.py(25)__init__()
-> response=b)
  /Users/moo/sits/parts/zope2/lib/python/ZPublisher/Publish.py(401)publish_module()
-> environ, debug, request, response)
  /Users/moo/sits/parts/zope2/lib/python/ZPublisher/Publish.py(202)publish_module_standard()
-> response = publish(request, module_name, after_list, debug=debug)
  /Users/moo/sits/parts/zope2/lib/python/ZPublisher/Publish.py(119)publish()
-> request, bind=1)
  /Users/moo/sits/parts/zope2/lib/python/ZPublisher/mapply.py(88)mapply()
-> if debug is not None: return debug(object,args,context)
  /Users/moo/sits/parts/zope2/lib/python/ZPublisher/Publish.py(42)call_object()
-> result=apply(object,args) # Type s<cr> to step into published object.
  <string>(4)_facade()
  /Users/moo/sits/parts/zope2/lib/python/AccessControl/requestmethod.py(64)_curried()
-> return callable(*args, **kw)
  /Users/moo/sits/eggs/Products.CMFCore-2.1.2-py2.4.egg/Products/CMFCore/WorkflowTool.py(457)updateRoleMappings()
-> count = self._recursiveUpdateRoleMappings(portal, wfs)
  /Users/moo/sits/eggs/Products.CMFCore-2.1.2-py2.4.egg/Products/CMFCore/WorkflowTool.py(609)_recursiveUpdateRoleMappings()
-> count = count + self._recursiveUpdateRoleMappings(v, wfs)
  /Users/moo/sits/eggs/Products.CMFCore-2.1.2-py2.4.egg/Products/CMFCore/WorkflowTool.py(609)_recursiveUpdateRoleMappings()
-> count = count + self._recursiveUpdateRoleMappings(v, wfs)
  /Users/moo/sits/eggs/Products.CMFCore-2.1.2-py2.4.egg/Products/CMFCore/WorkflowTool.py(609)_recursiveUpdateRoleMappings()
-> count = count + self._recursiveUpdateRoleMappings(v, wfs)
  /Users/moo/sits/eggs/Products.CMFCore-2.1.2-py2.4.egg/Products/CMFCore/WorkflowTool.py(609)_recursiveUpdateRoleMappings()
-> count = count + self._recursiveUpdateRoleMappings(v, wfs)
  /Users/moo/sits/eggs/Products.CMFCore-2.1.2-py2.4.egg/Products/CMFCore/WorkflowTool.py(609)_recursiveUpdateRoleMappings()
-> count = count + self._recursiveUpdateRoleMappings(v, wfs)
  /Users/moo/sits/eggs/Products.CMFCore-2.1.2-py2.4.egg/Products/CMFCore/WorkflowTool.py(600)_recursiveUpdateRoleMappings()
-> ob.reindexObject(idxs=['allowedRolesAndUsers'])
  /Users/moo/sits/eggs/Products.Archetypes-1.5.11-py2.4.egg/Products/Archetypes/CatalogMultiplex.py(115)reindexObject()
-> c.catalog_object(self, url, idxs=lst)
  /Users/moo/sits/eggs/Plone-3.3rc2-py2.4.egg/Products/CMFPlone/CatalogTool.py(417)catalog_object()
-> update_metadata, pghandler=pghandler)
  /Users/moo/sits/parts/zope2/lib/python/Products/ZCatalog/ZCatalog.py(536)catalog_object()
-> update_metadata=update_metadata)
  /Users/moo/sits/parts/zope2/lib/python/Products/ZCatalog/Catalog.py(348)catalogObject()
-> self.updateMetadata(object, uid)
  /Users/moo/sits/parts/zope2/lib/python/Products/ZCatalog/Catalog.py(277)updateMetadata()
-> newDataRecord = self.recordify(object)
  /Users/moo/sits/parts/zope2/lib/python/Products/ZCatalog/Catalog.py(417)recordify()
-> if(attr is not MV and safe_callable(attr)): attr=attr()
  /Users/moo/sits/products/SitsPatient/content/SitsPatient.py(2452)outSichECASS()
```

portal_workflow calls ob.reindexObject(idxs=['allowedRolesAndUsers']). However, this triggers refresh to all metadata.

1) Is this normal behavior?

2) Is this desired behavior?

3) Can I turn update_metadata off to speed up the process without breaking anything? Does portal security rely on metadata in any point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is normal behaviour. The catalog stores a subset of information that an object provides as a cache, so you can render pages with just catalog results without having to wake up the original objects. This includes the current workflow state for an object.

When reindexing, the catalog must update the metadata too, as it has no means of determining if that data has changed or not.

In this particular process, you cannot turn update_metadata off without patching; you'd have to either:

- patch Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.catalogObject to switch off update_metadata there,
- patch Products.Archetypes.CatalogMultiplex.CatalogMultiplex.reindexObject to call catalogObject with the update_metadata flag set to False,
- patch the workflow tool to call reindexObjectSecurity instead of reindexObject.

You'd have to audit your catalog schema (metadata) columns to see if nothing will indeed change when you update workflow security.

Comment: Ok. I might give this a test shot and hope maybe patches could end up to Plone core later. But it doesn't seem to be straightforward as I was hoping to :(